# How to use Solr Spellchecker at query time

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I have setup my solr schema as required by spellchecker to function. When I run a query with a wrongly spelled word, I get the following alongside the docs:

```
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[
      "jordun",{
        "numFound":1,
        "startOffset":0,
        "endOffset":6,
        "origFreq":0,
        "suggestion":[{
            "word":"jordan",
            "freq":33}]}],
    "correctlySpelled":true,
    "collations":[
      "collation","jordan"]}
```

However, the docs still return results for the incorrectly spelled word. Is there any way to return results for the first option in spellcheck suggestions without running another query?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another field to index which lists the options to the query which match the field of the spelling suggestions with the value of the word with the misspelling.